# Volume of tensor

Tags: matrices, tensors

For a $n\times n$ matrix, the volume is given by its determinant. In the case where $n=2$ the determinant is the area, in the case where $n=3$ it is the volume, and it generalizes to $n$ dimensions.

My question; Is there an equivalent to a volume formula/concept for a tensor? I have in mind a $4\times 4 \times 4 \times 4$ tensor if it helps.

Comment: You should make clear: the volume of what? The determinant of a matrix is the volume of the image of the standard parallelpiped, when you think of the $n\times n$ matrix as a linear map from $R^n \to R^n$. It might not be as easy to get a clear interpretation for your tensor, depending on its exact type.

Comment: @Keshav I am looking for a definition of the Riemannian volume form ($\omega=\sqrt{|g|}dx^1dx^2..dx^n$) which extends to tensor of degree 4 (or generally of degree n)

Comment: @AlexandreH.Tremblay The volume form $\omega$ allows you to calculate the volume of $n$ vectors in dimension $n$. That's all.